# JSON_OBJECT inside JSON_ARRAYAGG sometimes return json array, sometimes string

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

The `JSON_OBJECT` function strangely returns different data types depending on the presence of an key index in the join-table in MariaDB 10.5.12.

I've been trying to get post comments in a json array. And noticed that the output of the aggregate function changes strangely.

While it always gives the **same right results**, the packaging varies. Sometimes it's a `escaped string` requiring additional json parsing, sometimes it's a ready-made `json array`.

Gradually I was able to get close to the cause. Here's a minimally working piece of a query that shows the bug.

```
SELECT 
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT(
        'comment_id', comment.id, 
              'text', comment.text
    ) ORDER BY comment.id) AS comments
FROM post
LEFT JOIN comment ON comment.post_id = post.id
LEFT JOIN vote ON vote.user_id = 1 AND vote.post_id = post.id
GROUP BY post.id
```

**The prerequisite is that the key index `user_id` exists in the `vote` table.**

If the join *occurs* by the `user_id` field condition, the output is escaped string:

```
LEFT JOIN vote ON vote.user_id = 123 AND vote.post_id = post.id 

["{\"tag_id\": 1, \"name\": \"conubia\"}","{\"tag_id\": 21, \"name\": \"convallis\"}"]
["{\"tag_id\": 40, \"name\": \"amet\"}","{\"tag_id\": 41, \"name\": \"neque\"}"]
```

If the merge *does not* occur by the `user_id` field condition, the output is json array:

```
LEFT JOIN vote ON vote.user_id = -1 AND vote.post_id = post.id 

[{"tag_id": 1, "name": "conubia"},{"tag_id": 21, "name": "convallis"}]
[{"tag_id": 40, "name": "amet"},{"tag_id": 41, "name": "neque"}]
```

**If there is no key index `user_id`, under all join conditions, the output is escaped string:**

```
["{\"tag_id\": 1, \"name\": \"conubia\"}","{\"tag_id\": 21, \"name\": \"convallis\"}"]
["{\"tag_id\": 40, \"name\": \"amet\"}","{\"tag_id\": 41, \"name\": \"neque\"}"]
```

Vote DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `vote` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `post_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

### Question

Is it possible to prevent accidental changes to the function output by means of the database, without removing the index?

### Assumption

I think I could use CAST, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: have you thought about reporting this, but to reproduce it youi must add table and data aswell as create table and INsert into

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that, too. But I'm still in the process of researching and wanted feedback from the community. And to start a post in case anyone in the future encounters such a problem.

Comment: This problem is no longer present in version 10.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was connected with the bugs in JSON escaping.

- https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26506
- https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21902
- https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22837

The problem has been fixed in the new releases. Tested in MariaDB 10.6.5.

Comment: Actually upgrading to MariaDB:10.6.5 didn't resolve my issue, but you pointed to the right solution. I upgraded to MariaDB:10.7.8 and it solved the issue. Many thanks.